# Having dash or url on MapRoute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, model-view-controller, maproute

I try to get url from users and provide MapRoute like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("checkUrl", "tools/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "tools" }, new { });
```

On this case, it's works for this url: **"/tools/www.domain.com/"**

But how could I manage such a url: **"/tools/www.domain.com/view/child/child/?id=4"**

Route can't find such a address.

Answer (score 0):

You can use catchall in nexy maproute or use it instead of id.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly pass the URL as a parameter. You have to pass in a query string.

Before passing the URL you have to encode the URL.

Refer my URL for pass "**/tools/www.domain.com/view/child/child/?id=4**" in below.

**http://localhost:54964/Home/Index?id=www.domain.com%2Fview%2Fchild%2Fchild%2F%3Fid%3D4**

I getting value in the id parameter in the method.

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
            return View();
}
```